# Upload selected file to FTP using PHP

Tags: php, file, ftp, upload

I want upload selected local file to FTP using PHP.

The local file is selected using `$_POST` method:

```
<form  method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="filename"/><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

And this upload try:

```
$source_file=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
$remote_file='/www/img/file.txt';



if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY)) 
{
echo "successfully uploaded $source_file\n";
} 
else 
{
echo "There was a problem while uploading $source_file\n";
}
```

Result:

> Warning: ftp_put(): Filename cannot be empty

`$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']` is empty.

I know that `$source_file` must be a path.
So, I have question: What is correct path of selected file?

Comment: Try to move the uploaded file first and then ftp it .https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 0):

**You should follow these steps**

(1) Move uploaded file to local server first

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';

$remote_file='/www/img/file.txt';

$source_file=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

$name = basename($_FILES["filename"]['tmp_name']);

$file_path = $uploads_dir."/".$name;

move_uploaded_file($source_file, $file_path);
```

(2) Give local server file path to ftp upload

```
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file_path, FTP_BINARY)) 
{
echo "successfully uploaded $source_file\n";
} 
else 
{
echo "There was a problem while uploading $source_file\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works :) 

I can upload all extension without *,PNG. Do you have idea how i can upload PNG file?

Comment: Yay Congrats @MaciejM

Comment: Yes because you are naming `$remote_file='/www/img/file.txt'` make it dynamic with extension you got from uploaded file